# How to delete entire file inside Firebase Storage, when a User deletes his or her profile?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-storage

A short summary of what I'm trying to do:

If a user deletes their account, the folder on Firebase Storage that belongs to the user should also be deleted. The user's images are stored in Firebase Storage. Firebase Storage is structured as follows: users / UID of the user / images. At least one image and a maximum of 9 images are stored in the user's profile on Firebase Storage.

Would someone please send me an example of how to delete the user's folder based on his UID? I program in Flutter / Dart. I've looked at and implemented a number of examples on Stackoverflow and generally on the Internet, but nothing worked for me.

I'm using the following firebase_storage version: firebase_storage: ^ 3.1.6

Comment: Instead of asking us to provide you with code, show us what you tried and where you got stuck. Doing so will make it much more likely that someone can help. For more on this, I recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The problem is, I don't know how to delete things from storage. That is my biggest problem... :( Deleting from Firestore is pretty easy. :)

Comment: I recommend having a look at the documentation on deleting files in that case: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/delete-files While that link is for Android, the flow is the same across all platforms. Then when you understand the flow, you can look at the specific API for Flutter here: https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_storage/latest/firebase_storage/firebase_storage-library.html If you get stuck after those, we can help better if you show where you got stuck.

Comment: Thank you @ Frank van Puffelen! I will do so and than come back with more information. :)

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen: I tried out to use the example shown on the link you have send me, but I think this is not written in Dart. I just try to delete the folder inside Storage, that is conected with the UID of a User.

Comment: The second link I provided is the Flutter/Dart reference doc. Between the two links you should really be able to figure out the syntax. If you're getting stuck: show us a [minimal, complete/standalone example that reproduces where you are stick](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (please study this link too, as it's quite useful).

Comment: I am desperate. I really can not figure out how to do it... :(

Comment: This is the method you'll need to call: https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_storage/latest/firebase_storage/Reference/delete.html Did you do that? What happened? And seriously: it's much more likely we can help you if we can see what you've done.